# How can one restore buffers on startup in correct order?

Tags: buffers, start-up, desktop

I use `desktop-save-mode` in order to restore buffers on startup.  However, the buffer which is visible immediately after startup is `*scratch*`, `*Messages*`, `.bbdb`, etc.  I am not interested in those.  Is there a way to have Emacs after a restart in the same buffer state, including ordering, as when it was closed?

Answer (score 4):

I have the following in my equivalent of a .emacs file:

```el
(defun my-bury-star-buffers ()
  "Bury all star buffers."
  (interactive)
  (mapc (lambda (buf)
          (when (string-match-p "\\`\\*.*\\*\\'" (buffer-name buf))
            (bury-buffer buf)))
        (buffer-list)))
(add-hook 'desktop-after-read-hook #'my-bury-star-buffers)
```

I don't remember where I got it.  You'll need to extend the regex for any other files you want buried (like .bbdb).  The non-buried buffers seem to be in the right order.

Comment: Is it safe to just kill them?

Comment: @TorstenBronger, it's safe to kill the "star" buffers, but not recommended.  The `*Messages*` buffer will just come back next time a message is generated, but you will have lost all messages that happened before.  And the `*scratch*` buffer can be handy, but easily recreated if necessary.

Comment: I thought about it again and I remember that "File xy has recoverable data" messages have been important to me quite often.  Thus, I don't feel comfortable with just killing all star buffers.  Of course, one could switch your code off if one sees such messages in the minibuffer blinking during start-up and re-start Emacs; but I wouldn't know what annoys more.